# Cannot figure where clause in Linq that excludes values.

Tags: linq, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I am creating a repository that using entity framework (also domain objects) and I need to query all records that does not contain value "BADGE/" (undesired value).  I found a method that is ".Contains", but cannot find something equivalent to "notContains" or way to exclude records that have the undesired value. I would like the replace "p.Lname.Contains("BADGE/") with something like "p.Lname.NotContains("BADGE/") or something like that where it excludes the values during the return.  Here is what I have so far:

```
       public IQueryable<Personnel> NoBadgePersonnels
       {
           get {
                 return Context.Personnels.Where(p => p.Lname.Contains("BADGE/"));
           }

       }
```

additionally, this what my context looks like:

```
public class EmployeeRepository
{
    private readonly EFContextProvider<EmployeeDbContext>
   _contextProvider = new EFContextProvider<EmployeeDbContext>();


         private EmployeeDbContext Context
         {
             get { return _contextProvider.Context; }
         }
```

thanks community
Nick

Comment: did you try Where(p => !p.Lname.Contains("BADGE/") ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
return Context.Personnels.Where(p => p.Lname.IndexOf("BADGE/") == -1);
```

This excludes any strings which contain your target string.